# What are Redis "out_" prefix keys?

Tags: redis

I am seeing multiple out_ prefix keys in  my Redis ( version 3+ ) . Can any one help me understand these keys ? Are these internal , temporary keys ?

The application does not create these keys .

```
[02.66%] Biggest zset   found so far 'out_GVwthhmz' with 765025 members
[09.91%] Biggest zset   found so far 'out_JIwnd8Cu' with 798580 members
[69.70%] Biggest zset   found so far 'out_UcP6p4YL' with 801308 members
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are no internal/temporary keys that Redis creates - these are definitely something that was created by an application. Good luck hunting for it - possible routes to investigate:

1. Run `grep out_*` on your source code
2. Use `MONITOR` and `CLIENT LIST` to hone onto the offender